# Exclusive access to edit rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm developing a program that allows users to view and edit data.
My question:
Is there tools (sql server tools, may be users/roles) to implement the following:
There are two users: A and B. User A opened the edit form for row, at this point the user B can not edit the same row.

*I know, that i can use colunm for store UserId(user, which edit this row), but this solution is not suitable.*

Comment: Why you think that storing `UserId` is not a suitable solution?

Comment: @vijayp if the user will be disconnected (network or electrical power problem), row will be not available for edit. I'm interested in built-in tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use optimistic locking.

Before displaying the update form, you retrieve all the original values from the database. Or, at a minimum, a column that is guaranteed to change on update, such as `last_update_date` or similar.

When updating you check that all values are still the same in your `where` clause. If the update fails to update any rows you know that the values have been changed in between and inform the user that this has happened.

Comment: Thanks for good idea! How you think can i use db account for my problem somehow?

Comment: You should look into adding a column of type `ROWVERSION` to your table(s).

Comment: Upvoted.  I think this may be the most practical explanation of optimistic locking I've read in quite some time.  Thanks @Colin'tHart!

Comment: Which basically just described snapshot isolation (optimistic) and letting update conflicts act as your litmus without having to add another column: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb(v=vs.110).aspx